# iOS adding event to calendar is very slow?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekevent

I've added event to iphone calendar using this code

```
-(void)setEvent:(NSString *)title withStartDate:(NSDate *)startDate withEndDate:(NSDate *)endDate completion:(void (^)(void))completionBlock
{

    EKEventStore* store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (!granted)
        {
            return;
        }
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
        event.title = title;
        event.startDate = startDate;
        event.endDate = endDate;
        [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
        NSError *err = nil;
        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
       // NSString *savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier;
        NSString* alertTitle;
        NSString* msg;
        if (err) {

            alertTitle = @"Calendar was not set";
            msg = @"Please set default calendar in settings.";
        }
        else
        {
            alertTitle = @"Event added";
            msg = @"Event had been added in your calendar.";
        }
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        completionBlock();

    }];
}
```

but adding event is very slow.I've to wait about 10-12 seconds for completion of this method.Is this normal or i'm doing some thing wrong?I've searched for the same but still no luck.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it a local or remote calendar? Maybe it's trying to synchronize with an external calendar (Google Calendar for instance) if it's selected as the default one...

Comment: How to check that? however events are added to native calendar app of iOS.

Comment: Configuration -> Email,contacts,cal -> Calendars -> Default Calendar . If you configure a GMail account, it's calendar is selected by default.

Comment: no account has added, and Default Calendar is set to Calendar?? same thing on simulator also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some 2 days research i found the solution-i put the event saving code in `dispatch_async` here is my updated method for adding event-

```
-(void)setEvent:(NSString *)title withStartDate:(NSDate *)startDate withEndDate:(NSDate *)endDate withResecheduling:(BOOL)rescheduling completion:(void (^)(void))completionBlock
{

    [[BusyIndicator sharedInstance] startIndicator];
    EKEventStore* store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (!granted)
        {
            return;
        }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
                    event.title = title;
                    event.startDate = startDate;
                    event.endDate = endDate;
                    [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
                    NSError *err = nil;
                    [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
                    // NSString *savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier;
                    if (!rescheduling) {

                        NSString* alertTitle;
                        NSString* msg;
                        if (err) {

                            alertTitle = @"Calendar was not set";
                            msg = @"Please set default calendar in settings.";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alertTitle = @"Event added";
                            msg = @"Event has been added in your calendar.";
                        }
                        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                        [alert show];
                    }

                    [[BusyIndicator sharedInstance] stopIndicator];
                    completionBlock();
        });


    }];
}
```

Comment: I was seeing the same sort of thing - 10-30 seconds delay in the block when trying to present UI for the user to select a calendar, either with my own UI or EKCalendarChooser. Anyway, the async dispatch fixed that for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
  [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
```

by

```
  [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

Comment: sorry it is more slower !!

Comment: you are checking on which ios version? below 6 has another way

Comment: on iOS 6.1 and iOS7 and date format is 2013-10-15 20:00:00 +0000, i'm getting it from a webservice.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this....

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

if([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])
{
    // iOS 6 and later
    // This line asks user's permission to access his calendar
    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if (granted) // user user is ok with it
         {
             EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
             event.title  = eventname;
             event.allDay = NO;                 

             event.startDate = StartDateobject; // StartDateObject is Object of Date Class
             event.endDate=event.startDate;

             [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
             NSError *err;

             [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];

             if(err)
             {

                 NSLog(@"Unable to save event to the calendar!: Error= %@", err);

             }
             else
             {

                 NSLog(@"Event added successfully.");

             }
         }

     }];
}

// iOS < 6
else
{
    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    event.title  = eventname;
    event.allDay = NO;

    event.startDate = StartDateobject; // StartDateObject is Object of Date Class
    event.endDate=event.startDate;


    [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSError *err;

    [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];

    if(err)
    {

         NSLog(@"unable to save event to the calendar!: Error= %@", err);

    }
    else
    {

        NSLog(@"Event added successfully..");

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of dateString and what is StartDateobject? and what about commit the save?means how it will be committed?